# como llamar varias id en un codigo javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero llamar varias id en el codigo javascript para no tener que crear un codigo diferente para cada boton de **Mostrar más:**

```
<p><a href="javascript:mostrar();">Mostrar</a></p><div id="flotante"style="display:none;"><div id="close"><a href="javascript:cerrar();">cerrar</a></div> --CONTENIDO--</div>
```

Ya he intentado pero no funciona, también he intentado con ByClassName pero tampoco, alguien sabe como hago? codigo **Javascript**

```
function mostrar() {
        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = '';
    }

    function cerrar() {
        div = document.getElementById('flotante');
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: En tu lugar intentaría redactar un poco distinto el problema, no se entiende bien qué quieres hacer

Comment: es decir meter varios elementos en document.getElementById ejemplo (div = document.getElementById('flotante, flotante2, flotante3 etc...');

Comment: Si no podes usar clases en tu problema, deberías usar `querySelectorAll` ahí te deje un ejemplo

Comment: Sin embargo, te recomiendo que leas acerca de `Id` y `class` en html/css/javascript, ya que por lo general, seleccionar múltiples id no se si es lo más común, cuando se da el caso, suele aplicar el concepto de ´class´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo general, cuando uno busca un elemento por su id, suele ser único, sino, el uso de `class` en lugar de `id` se vuelve más lógico, sin embargo, si es necesario seleccionar múltiples elementos, puede hacerse usando `document.querySelectorAll`, por ejemplo

```js
function Ejemplo()
{
  //Uso querySelectorAll para seleccionar los elementos con id uno, dos y tres.
  var Elementos = document.querySelectorAll('#uno, #dos, #tres');

  //uso forEach para recorrer el arreglo de elementos que obtuve arriba
  Elementos.forEach(function(item){
    //Cambio el color de cada uno a fin de ejemplo
    item.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });  
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 10px;  
}
button
{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
<div id="tres"></div>
<button onclick="Ejemplo()">¡Probar!</button>
```

Aclaración: ignorar el css del snippet que es puramente del ejemplo

---

Sin embargo, como menciono al principio de la respuesta, si no hay algún requisito en particular que te impida hacerlo, lo ideal sería el uso de `class`, ya que aplicar el mismo comportamiento a varios `id`, sería lo mismo ¿no?

Para hacerlo, un snippet podría ser el siguiente:

```js
function Ejemplo()
{ 
  //Selecciono todos los elementos con la class 'clase'
  var Elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('clase');
  
  //Recorro el array obtenido
  [].forEach.call(Elementos, function (item) {
    //Cambio el color del div por fines demostrativos.
    item.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });  
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 10px;  
}
button
{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clase"></div>
<div class="clase"></div>
<div class="clase"></div>
<button onclick="Ejemplo()">Probar!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Es cierto, getElementById solo retorna 1 valor.
Si agregas class="flotante" a tus divs, podrías obtener la lista con alguna de las opciones:

```
 getElementsByClassName("flotante")
 querySelectorAll("div.flotante")
```

Comment: La 2da opcion solo funciona si el tipo de tag es div. La 1era aplica a span o cualquier tag que tenga la clase "flotante"